# SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NodeManager at DESKTOP-35PPBFF, SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down ResourceManager at DESKTOP-35PPBFF

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

Hadoop 3.3.0, native IO binary:[winutils-master](https://github.com/ruslanmv/How-to-install-Hadoop-on-Windows/tree/master/winutils/hadoop-3.3.0-YARN-8246/bin), jdk17.0.2, windows 11;

configuration of mapred-site.xml

```
    <configuration>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
</property>
<property> 
    <name>mapreduce.application.classpath</name>
    <value>%HADOOP_HOME%/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*,%HADOOP_HOME%/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*,%HADOOP_HOME%/share/hadoop/common/*,%HADOOP_HOME%/share/hadoop/common/lib/*,%HADOOP_HOME%/share/hadoop/yarn/*,%HADOOP_HOME%/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*,%HADOOP_HOME%/share/hadoop/hdfs/*,%HADOOP_HOME%/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*</value>
</property>
```

configuration of yarn-site.xml

```
    <configuration>
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.env-whitelist</name>
    <value>JAVA_HOME,HADOOP_COMMON_HOME,HADOOP_HDFS_HOME,HADOOP_CONF_DIR,CLASSPATH_PREPEND_DISTCACHE,HADOOP_YARN_HOME,HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME</value>
</property>
```

when i run this command:
C:\Windows\System32>%HADOOP_HOME%\sbin\start-yarn.cmd

after these commands:
C:\Windows\System32>hdfs namenode -format
C:\Windows\System32>%HADOOP_HOME%\sbin\start-dfs.cmd

then i am getting these result which must not happen:
[nodemanager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2qoo.png)
[resourcemanager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pt1rQ.png)

i just want to keep running resourcemanager and nodemanager until i will not stop by using command or manually. please give me solution of this problem as soon as possible.